# Evitar mostrar anteriores gráficos Doughnut (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy usando Doughnut para crear gráficas con información almacenada en una base de datos mysql. Cuando selecciono un determinado año y mes (yyyy-mm) usando el plugin MonthPicker se genera el gráfico en base a ese período:

```
<canvas id="canvasCake" class="canvasCake" height="300" width="300" style="margin: 15px 10px 10px 0"></canvas>
<input id="period" name="period" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Period">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cada vez que voy seleccionando períodos crea un nuevo gráfico y al pasarle el mouse muestra los gráficos anteriores que he generado y el gráfico actual a la vez, el código fuente aparece de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado cambiar mi código poniendo usando **destroy** al final:

```
var chart_doughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvasCake"), chart_doughnut_settings);
chart_doughnut.destroy();
```

Funciona bien, pero el problema es que ya no muestra los tooltips al pasarle el mouse como antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer que muestra los tooltips al pasarle el mouse pero evitando que no muestre los gráficos anteriores?

Este es mi código **JS** actual:

```
$('#period').MonthPicker({ Button: false, MonthFormat: 'yy-mm',OnAfterChooseMonth: function(){ 
  var period = $("#period").val();
  graphCake(period);
}});

function graphCake(date){
   $.ajax({
     url: "myfile.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {fecha: date},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(resp)
     {
        var client01 = resp[0];
        var percent01 = resp[1];

        show_cake(client01,percent01);    
     }
   });
} 

function show_cake(lbl,dtd){

  var chart_doughnut_settings = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
    data: {       
    labels: lbl,
    datasets: [{        
    data: dtd,
    backgroundColor: ["#bdc3c7","#9b59b6","#e74c3c","#26b99a","#fff200","#3498db","#634517","#f49104","#85ca19","#006b6a","#51c5cf","#4fd167","#861106","#550469","#0e6f97","#e4e23d","#df0064","#306ed6"],
    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#d2d4d6","#ba68dc","#f33e2b","#25deb7","#fff878","#58b7f6","#845a19","#ffbd5f","#9fe72f","#129291","#4bdfec","#8cf9a0","#a63429","#7a1c91","#288bb4","#f0ee5a","#fa5ba2","#4f8cf0"]
   }]
  },
   options: { 
    legend: false, 
    responsive: false 
  } 
 }

  var chart_doughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvasCake"), chart_doughnut_settings);
} //show_cake
```

Answer (score -1):

Antes de agregar la información, intenta eliminar el `iframe` del `DOM`:

Ejemplo:

```
$(".canvasCake iframe").remove()
```

Comment: debes leer [answer] y explicar por que?

Comment: si hace lo que le dices explica el por que?

Comment: si, que pena, lo que pasa es que cada que agregas la información que traes en el canvas, se crea un <iframe> y se va acumulando lo que tenias antes con lo nuevo y por eso al pasar el mouse por encima se muestranlas graficas vieja(s) con la nueva